# How do I access all page objects in django-cms from every page?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I am using Django CMS 2.1.0.beta3 and am encountering a problem. I need to have access to all the pages in a variable so that I can loop through them and create my navigation menu using a for loop. The show_menu functionality provided with django cms will not work for what I am doing.

I need a queryset with all pages so I can do something similar to the following:

```
{% for page in cms_pages %}
    {{ page.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Does anyone know how I can gain access to all the published page objects like that on **ALL** pages?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by creating a templatetag in django that serves up all of the cms pages:

app/template_tags/navigation_tags.py:

```
from django import template
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page

register = template.Library()

def cms_navigation():
    cms_pages = Page.objects.filter(in_navigation=True, published=True)
    return {'cms_pages': cms_pages}

register.inclusion_tag('main-navigation.html')(cms_navigation)
```

Then in the templates you call the template tag as follows:

```
{% load navigation_tags %} {% cms_navigation %}
```

This requires that you have a main-navigation.html file created. Here then the HTML from that template will be injected into the template wherever the tag is and the main-navigation.html will have access to whatever was passed to it in the custom tag function:

templates/main-navigation.html:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    {% for page in cms_pages %}
         {{ page.get_title }}
    {% endfor %}    
</ul>
```

I hope this helps someone better understand templatetags. I found the documentation a bit confusing on this subject.

Comment: Eight years later, the documentation is still mostly examples. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @random6174 awesome I'm glad this is still helpful!

Answer (score 3):

According to the doc you should use:

```
Page.objects.public()
```

source: https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/support/2.4.x/cms/models/managers.py#L31

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Page model to get all published pages.

```
Page.objects.published()
```

You can use this in your views or plugins

Regards
Miro
migaat.blogspot.com

Comment: I realize you can do this but how do I make that available to all page templates?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this where you want the page.

```
{{ request.current_page }}
```

This worked for me.
You may need to have included `{% load staticfiles %}` somewhere in your code